# How to encrypt an image with logistic chaotic map?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design

I need to encrypt color images, using logistic chaotic map. Could you please recommend an algorithm for this?

All the articles that I've found on the Internet are completely unclear.

Comment: [Did you see this paper](http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/2014/Istanbul/TELEDU/TELEDU-37.pdf)? Or were you looking for an actual implementation?

Comment: @E. Rose: the paper contains: _"The proposed_ (sic) _is a simple block cipher with block size of 8-bit and 256-bit secret key"_. The drawing below that shows something that could be block cipher in CFB mode, and an 8-bit block cipher in CFB mode can't be safe. So the system in the paper is unsafe, OR the paper is unclear (with _OR_ being used in it's inclusive form).

Comment: @fgrieu duly noted, and thank you for the observation. That was basically the extent of what I found searching for logistic map encryption. This was the first I had heard of it. I only skimmed the paper in question, to be honest I was assuming OP had already seen it and was looking for something else anyways.

Comment: Correction: the drawing is not quite CFB, even if you notice that the top feekback is cancelled: there are 2 bytes of key input from a 256-byte circular buffer at each step. I'm leaning towards unclear and unsafe. @Yuriy N.: you may need to encrypt a color image; but why would you need to use a logistic chaotic map for that purpose? If that's an assignment, can you politely repel the _"logistic chaotic map"_ part of it as unacademic, and replace it by something that is?

Comment: other than randomness tests of output, chaotic ciphers have no proof of security and should be avoided.

Comment: @fgrieu I've read this article "Robust Watermarking Technique using 2D Logistic Map and Elliptic Curve Cryptosystem in Wavelets", so I need logistic map image encryption algorithm. I've found this article ["Image encryption using the two-dimensional logistic chaotic map"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258660674_Image_encryption_using_the_two-dimensional_logistic_chaotic_map), but I've stuck almost at first chapter, at Logistic Permutation. So, I want to find more clear article, to clarify this question.